# JavaScript: Writing a reduce function, trouble with callback function that subtracts values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I'm working to solve a code challenge in JavaScript where I am tasked with creating a function, called reduce, that will reduce a collection to a value which is the accumulated result of calling a function on each item over which I've iterated. The three parameters to include are array, callback, and start. Start is the index at which to begin, and if not provided as an argument defaults to the index zero.

Below is what I have currently:

```
function reduce(array, callback, start) {
    if(typeof start === 'number'){
        var initVal = start;
    } else {
        var initVal = 0;
    }
    return array.reduce(callback, initVal);
}
```

I have some tests against which I can test my solution, and my current work is failing only one test involving a callback function that subtracts the values. Here is the test I'm currently failing:

```
var difference = function(tally, item) {return tally - item; };
var total = reduce([1, 2, 3], difference);
expect(total).to.equal(-4);
```

Guidance is greatly appreciated.

---

Edited to add working solution:

```
function reduce(array, callback, start) {
    if( typeof start === 'undefined' ){
        return array.reduce(callback);
    } else {
        return array.reduce(callback, start);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are supposed to not use the `Array.prototype.reduce` but iterate the array manually. What makes me thinking so: `start` is as you explained the index to start with, not the initial value.

Comment: You're setting the initial value to `0`, not to the item at index `0`, so you get `0 - 1 - 2 - 3 == -6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work since you're misusing the `start` which is intended to be an element index to start with with the initial value.

So for the `[1, 2, 3]` array as an input and the subtraction function as a callback what you are getting is:

1. The reducer accumulator is initialised with `0` (what you are supposed to not do actually)
2. `0 - 1 -> -1`
3. `-1 - 2 -> -3`
4. `-3 - 3 -> -6`

What you should have done instead:

1. There is no third parameter passed, so you're iterating from the beginning of the array.
2. Accumulator is not initialised explicitly, so the first element is passed to it, hence `acc = 1`
3. `1 - 2 -> -1`
4. `-1 - 3 -> -4`

Comment: I think expecting `-4` is the weird thing here that should not have been done…

Comment: @Bergi `[1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, v) => acc - v) // -4` ? But I agree, the reduce/fold function **must** have the initial value as a mandatory argument.

Comment: Yes, sure it works, I'm arguing that he should rather change the test than the implementation which imo is correct (`foldr` is better than `foldr1`).

Comment: What would be the proper logic to check for the presence of the start parameter?

Comment: @campallison compare it with the `undefined`. Eg: `start === undefined` means it "was not passed". Your implementation `typeof start === 'number'` is also fine.

Comment: I reworked it to this:

`function reduce(array, callback, start) {
 if( typeof start === 'undefined' ){
  return array.reduce(callback, 0); 
 } else {
  return array.reduce(callback, start);
 }
}`

but I know the second parameter in the block of the if statement is problematic. Specifically, the zero. `array[0]` Also doesn't work. I do understand what you communicated in your initial answer, but I'm just stuck (due to lack of experience) with what would give me the correct `start` if `start` isn't given as an argument.

Comment: @campallison as I mentioned in the comment - you're supposed to implement it **WITHOUT** using the built-in `reduce` function, just using a loop.